# inspiration from Different Differences (codeforces problem 1772c)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

[link to problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1772/C)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

 import java.util.Scanner;

class Codechef { static boolean test(int[]a,int n){

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

 if(a[i]-a[i+1]>0)

 System.out.println("not si");

return false;
        
    }
    return true;
}
static int[] array(int[]a,int n){
    int[] a1=new int[n-1];
    if(test(a,n )){
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            a1[i]=a[i+1]=a[i];
        }
    }
    return a1;
}
static int type(int[]a,int n){
    int c=0;
    int []k=array(a, n);
    Arrays.sort(k);
    for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
        if(k[i]!=k[i+1])c++;
    }
    return c;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Array & no of elements");
    int n=in.nextInt();
    int []a=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    a[i]=in.nextInt();
    int c=type(a, n);
    System.out.println(c);

}`
```

the following code gives the output:
`Array & no of element`
 `5`
`0`
`2` 
`8`
`10`
`16` 
`0 (output)`
clearly not the desired results. So where am i going wrong? please enlighten me.

Ive tried a set of "nested" methods and was expecting for the value of c to be greater than zero...

Comment: Why do you print "Array & no of elements" in the first place? These kinds of tasks don't like random debug output

Comment: @zapl to accept and no of elements from the user. where could I improve?